# Bigquery aggregating into array based on id and id_type

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
WITH
  table AS (
  SELECT 1 object_id, 234 type_id, 2 type_level UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 23, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 24, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 34, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 46, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 465, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 349, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 0 )
SELECT
  object_id,
  type_id,
  type_level
FROM
  table
```

[image]

Now I am trying to create three new columns `type_level_0_array`,`type_level_1_array`,`type_level_2_array` for each object and aggregate the type_id of corresponding level of types into those array (I am not looking for string separated by commas).

So my resultant table should look like the following:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id | type_level_0_array | type_level_1_array | type_level_2_array |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | 2                  | 24,23              | 234                |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2  | 3,4                | 34,46              | 465,349            |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Update:

Although it seems that my type_id has certain pattern e.g. level 0 types are of 1 length, level 1 types are of 2 length and so on, in my real dataset there is no such pattern. The identification of level is solely possible by looking at `type_level` of any row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT object_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(type_level = 0, type_id, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_0_array,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(type_level = 1, type_id, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_1_array,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(type_level = 2, type_id, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_2_array
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY object_id
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 object_id, 234 type_id, 2 type_level UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 23, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 24, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 34, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 46, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 465, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 349, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 0 )
SELECT object_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(type_level = 0, type_id, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_0_array,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(type_level = 1, type_id, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_1_array,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(type_level = 2, type_id, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_2_array
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY object_id
```

with result

```
Row     object_id   type_level_0_array  type_level_1_array  type_level_2_array   
1       1           2                   24                  234  
                                        23       
2       2           4                   34                  349  
                    3                   46                  465
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works for me.

Bigquery won't let you create an array with Nulls in them, which is why the IGNORE NULLS is required.

EDIT: I've updated the code to be based off the type_level column

```
WITH table
 AS (
  SELECT 1 object_id, 234 type_id, 2 type_level UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 23, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 24, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 34, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 46, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 465, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 349, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 0 )
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN type_level = 0 THEN type_id ELSE NULL END IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_0_array
  , ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN type_level = 1 THEN type_id ELSE NULL END IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_1_array
  , ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN type_level = 2 THEN type_id ELSE NULL END IGNORE NULLS) AS type_level_2_array
FROM
  table
```

Comment: Hi paul, although it seems that all the level 0 are 1 digit and level 1 are 2 digits and so on, in my real dataset all of them has same length id.